# Beautifulsoup4 not returning all links on the page

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, html-parsing

I am working on a web crawler with Python 3.5. Using Requests and Beautifulsoup4. I am trying to get the links to all the topics on the first page of a Forum. and add them to a list.

I have 2 issues:

1) Not sure how to get the link using beautifulsoup, I could not get in to the link itself, just the div
2) It seems that Beautifulsoup is returning only a few topics, not all of them.

```
def getTopics():
topics = []
url = 'http://forum.jogos.uol.com.br/pc_f_40'
source_code = requests.get(url)
plain_text = source_code.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')

for link in soup.select('[class="topicos"]'):
    a = link.find_all('a href')
    print (a)
```

getTopics()

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it actually loops over all the 38 topics presented on the page.

The actual problem is in how you are extracting the links for each topic - `link.find_all('a href')` would find you nothing since there is no `a href` elements on the page. Replace it with `link.select('a[href]')` - it would find you all `a` elements having `href` attribute.

---

Well, you may even solve it with a single list comprehension:

```
topics = [a["href"] for a in soup.select('.topicos a[href]')]
```